# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, undefined, chart.js, typeerror

I'm using the angular-chartjs, and I get the following error when I resize the screen:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

This is the directive:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-legend="true" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
```

And the JS:

```
 $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.series = [];
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.onClick = function(points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
    };
    $scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }];
    $scope.options = {
        responsive: true,
        pointDot: false,
        scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        showTooltips: false,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'asdsadsdsad'
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },           
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'y-axis-1',
                type: 'linear',
                display: true,
                position: 'left'
            }]
        },
    };
    $http.get($scope.url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.series.push('ASD');
        $scope.series.push('QWE');
        var dataArray = [];
        var dataArrayT = [];            
        var labels = [];
        var progress = 1;
        var month = 0;
        var progressT=1.2;
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            progress += progress * d.change;
            progressT += progressT * d.change;
            if (month !== d.month) {
                labels.push(d.month);
                month = d.month;
            } else {
                labels.push('');
            }
            dataArray.push(progress);
            dataArrayT.push(progressT);
        });

        $scope.labels = labels;
        $scope.data.push(dataArray);
        $scope.data.push(dataArrayT);

    });
```

Data added to the charts are roughly 400 points.

I only get the error when I resize the screen, so it's not that it can't handle a different size, it's just that it doesn't work as responsive.